# app application request popup filter users

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to invite only girls to my app in FB.ui popup ?

thank You for any suggestions, if not tneh maybe there is any other solution available ?

User is in the app. There is invite friends button with jscode:

```
 $('#btnInvite').bind("click", function(){
        FB.ui({method:'apprequests',title:'test',message:'test',data:'test'});
    })
```

And then popup with friends appears to be selected. Is it possible to filter this list only to female users (app is dedicated for girls)

Comment: I assume your intentions are good, but without context this question is incredibly creepy.

Comment: lol! man that question should be a huge success if answered

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable.

However, you're going to have to go thru some extra hoops to get it done.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/, you can see that is possible for you to specify a list of friend ids for the app to send to.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends, you can get a list of friends. And look for females.
Or you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/ and look for female friends `fql?q=SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) and sex="female"`

Present the female friends list to the user to allow them to select which ones.

Concatenate together the selected female friend ids and pass that to the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ request's dialog's `to` field.

Le Voila! Finis! :)